# While loop could not satisfies the condition for constraning the values of parameters

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to repeat the computation step until the value is within the defined range, such as `0.2` to `0.29`.  When this code runs, we see the value goes more than `0.29` and in some cases we have `0.01`or even `-0.1` which is negative.
How do I fix this?

```
import numpy as np
from math import *
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

N=1000
Omo  = np.zeros((N,))
Omo[0]=0.24
Omn = np.zeros((N,))

for i in range (1,N):
            R=np.random.uniform()
            num=0
            while True:
                num+=1
                Omn[i]=Omo[i-1]+0.01*np.random.normal()

                L=2*Omn[i]      # Arbitrary equation just for test

                if L>R:
                   Omo[i]=Omn[i]

                else:
                    Omo[i]=Omo[i-1]

                if (Omo[i]<0 and Omo[i]>0.29) or num>100:
                    break

                print(Omo[i],L)
```

Comment: `Omo[i]<0 and Omo[i]>0.29` doesn't look right to me. Can you name a number that's less than zero and greater than 0.29 at the same time?

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: You haven't defined any range; in fact, `0.2` doesn't appear in your program.  You haven't described what you expect this to do, and your variable names don't explain anything.  You've made it particularly difficult for us to help you.

Comment: @Kevin I wante to say of `Om` is bigger than `0.29` and if `Om` is smaller than `0.2` break. just stay between these two values

Comment: @Prune I want `Om` to stay between `0.2` and `0.29`. So, could you  tell me what should I do?

Comment: @Bob. Why can't you just pick a random value within the required range?

Comment: @ekhumoro what do you mean. How?

Comment: @Bob. [`np.random.uniform(0.2, 0.3)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html#numpy-random-uniform).

Answer (score 0):

If "`Om` is bigger than 0.29 and if `Om` is smaller than 0.2" is not mathematically possible.  From what you describe, I suspect you want `or`, not `and`.

```
if Omo[i] > 0.29 or Omo[i] < 0.2:
    break
```

This solves the immediate logic problem, but not the overall control problem.  This says to leave the loop if `Omo` is not in that range.  Your *stated* purpose is to stay in the loop until it gets *into* that range.  That should be coded into the loop control, something like

```
while Omo[i] > 0.29 or Omo[i] < 0.2:
```

Can you continue from there?

Also, I strongly recommend that you look carefully at class materials and a tutorial or two, so you can pick up recommended programming practices.  Meaningful variable names, preferred use of upper- and lower-case letters, and a variety of other small techniques can save you a lot of trouble, and get you help faster.

Comment: May be I asked in bad way. I want a value between 0.2 and 0.29. Because of it I wrote if it is less than 0.2 and bigger than 0.29 do not accept. I mean just numbers between 0.2 an 0.29,like 0.23, 0.287, 0.265

Comment: Good.  I believe I have clarified that in my edits to your posting.

Answer (score 0):

Why I have to answer your question continuously? :))
You are misunderstood. 
just turn the sign of your code.

```
while True:
            num+=1
            Omn[i]=Omo[i-1]+0.01*np.random.normal()

            L=2*Omn[i]      # Arbitrary equation just for test

            if L>R:
               Omo[i]=Omn[i]

            else:
                Omo[i]=Omo[i-1]

            if (0<Omo[i]<0.29) or num>100:
                break
print(Omo[i],L)
```